# What is this output from mongod in command prompt?

Tags: mongodb, command-prompt

I'm new to mongo, I've just installed it and it's working well.
running the command `mongod` in my command prompt (I'm using windows) and I can connect to it via MongoDB compass.
what Is confusing me is the output I get when running `mongod` it's like a javascript object that I don't understand. I've looked everywhere but couldn't understand

the command

```sh
C:\Users\moham> mongod
```

the output

```sh
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.401+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}  
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.404+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}                                                                                                             
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.404+01:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}                                                                    
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.404+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}                                                                                                   
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.406+01:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}                                                                    
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.406+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}} 
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.406+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.407+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":15624,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"1337-DELL-Latitude"}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.407+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}                      
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.408+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.3","gitVersion":"657fea5a61a74d7a79df7aff8e4bcf0bc742b748","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}                                                                                                                                      
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.408+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19042)"}}}                          
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.408+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}                                                                      
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.409+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}              
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.410+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3489M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}                                                                                                                                                    
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.432+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1634154158:431805][15624:140723815929168], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 2 through 3"}}                                                                                                                                                                                                             
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.482+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1634154158:481841][15624:140723815929168], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 3 through 3"}}                                                                                                                                                                                                             
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.542+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1634154158:541839][15624:140723815929168], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 2/18176 to 3/256"}}                                                                                                                                                                    
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.633+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1634154158:633806][15624:140723815929168], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 2 through 3"}}                                                                                                                                                                                                             
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.686+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1634154158:686841][15624:140723815929168], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 3 through 3"}}                                                                                                                                                                                                             
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.732+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1634154158:731808][15624:140723815929168], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}                                                                                                                                                                               
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.732+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1634154158:731808][15624:140723815929168], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}                                                                                                                                                                                 
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.733+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1634154158:732808][15624:140723815929168], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 1, snapshot max: 1 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 51"}}                                                                      
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.738+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":328}}                                                                        
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.738+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}                                 
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.740+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}     
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.742+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}                                                                                             
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.744+01:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.744+01:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.746+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915702, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Updated wire specification","attr":{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true},"newSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":13,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}                                                                                                                    
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.749+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":5071100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Clearing temp directory"}                                                                                                
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.749+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}                                                                             
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.899+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"C:/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}                   
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.903+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}                                                                                 
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:42:38.903+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}                                                                   
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:43:38.746+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1634154218:745736][15624:140723815929168], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 3, snapshot max: 3 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 51"}}                                                                       
{"t":{"$date":"2021-10-13T20:44:38.755+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1634154278:754933][15624:140723815929168], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 6, snapshot max: 6 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 51"}}
```

Comment: See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-60551

Comment: [see this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) to run the mongo shell, try  >mongo   not >mongod (mongod is the mongodb process)

Comment: That is the new format for mongod logs.

Comment: You can direct the log output from the console to a log file, by specifying proper options when starting the `mongod`.